# read from HIDDEV locks up

Tags: c, linux, usb, hid

I have the following code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <asm/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/hiddev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char name[128];
    sprintf(name, "/dev/usb/hiddev0");

    fprintf(stdout, "Using device %s\n", name);

    int fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EACCES)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "No permission, try this as root.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    ioctl(fd, HIDIOCGNAME(sizeof(name)), name);
    printf("HID device name: \"%s\"\n", name);

    struct hiddev_devinfo info;

    if (ioctl(fd, HIDIOCGDEVINFO, &info) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Found %d applications\n", info.num_applications);

    for (int i = 0; i != info.num_applications; i++)
    {
        unsigned usage = ioctl(fd, HIDIOCAPPLICATION, i);
        if (usage == -1)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        printf("Usages of Application[%u]: %0X\n", i, usage);
    }

    struct hiddev_report_info rinfo;
    rinfo.report_type = HID_REPORT_TYPE_INPUT;
    rinfo.report_id = HID_REPORT_ID_FIRST;
    if (ioctl(fd, HIDIOCGREPORT, &rinfo) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Getting Report failed\n");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Found %d fields\n", rinfo.num_fields);

    int flags = HIDDEV_FLAG_UREF;
    if (ioctl(fd, HIDIOCSFLAG, &flags) == -1)
    {
        return -5;
    }

    printf("Waiting on events\n");

    for (; 1;)
    {
        struct hiddev_usage_ref ev;

        if (read(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev)) != sizeof(ev))
        {
            return -4;
        }
        printf("Found {field_index: %d, report_id: %0X, report_type: %d, usage_code: %0X, usage_index: %u, value: %d}\n", ev.field_index, ev.report_id, ev.report_type, ev.usage_code, ev.usage_index, ev.value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With that I am able to `read` in the loop a few times but eventually `read` will stop to return (while there should be events present). Have not yet found what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For some strange reason if I change `int flags = HIDDEV_FLAG_UREF | HIDDEV_FLAG_REPORT;` then it seems to work indefinitely.

Comment: Maybe `read` only reports events that differ from last and ignores same events.